# Laravel do a fake migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration, database-migration

I word on a project which use Laravel migration.
I have a migration list :

```
2015_09_01_010101_table_orders
2015_09_02_010101_table_products
2015_09_03_010101_table_customers
```

I know that **2015_09_01** SQL migration are already in my database, but Laravel don't know it. So when I run **php artisan mig:run** Laravel shows me an **SQL Error**.

How can I do a fake migration ? I want that Laravel believes that I already use **2015_09_01** migration. With Django I can run a fake migration but I didn't find anything for Laravel.

Comment: does migration resides in database??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually add a new row in your `migrations` table:

```
--------------------------------------------
| migration                      |  batch  |
--------------------------------------------
| 2015_09_01_010101_table_orders |    1    |
--------------------------------------------
```

Laravel will check this table for migrations and skip those which are already present.

Comment: Thanks it works. I'm surprised that there aren't a php artisan mig:fake 2015_09_01 command.